# Balena-Enginer (docker) error while copying file to container

Tags: docker, cp, balena

I have created a balena-engine container.
ID of the container is fa2c14de228d.

When I am copying a file, say some text file from host to a container with id fa2c14de228d,
I am having the following error.

```
root@axcf2152:/opt# balena-engine cp test.txt fa2c14de228d:/opt/FT/
SIGILL: illegal instruction
PC=0x52c6e m=6 sigcode=1

goroutine 0 [idle]:
runtime: unexpected return pc for runtime.dumpregs called from 0xb3b35527
stack: frame={sp:0xb4e8aa1c, fp:0xb4e8aa7c} stack=[0xb468b0d4,0xb4e8acd4)
b4e8a99c:  00000000  62cc4f93  00000000  00000000
b4e8a9ac:  00000000  b39e5230  b3bf515c  00000000
b4e8a9bc:  b3b3d9fd  b3bf4cc4  b3bf515c  b3b8c0fb
b4e8a9cc:  b3b3d04f  b3b3cf5d  b39e5230  0000000a
b4e8a9dc:  00000000  a528859e  3fd4689f  5ae0c2ae
b4e8a9ec:  3fe8e8db  0148430c  0000000a  b3bf4fb8
b4e8a9fc:  b4e8aa40  0000000a  b4573108  b39e5230
b4e8aa0c:  00000001  b4e8b7c0  b4e8aa48  00000000
b4e8aa1c: <b3b35527  b39e5210  b4e8aa44  b4e8b7c0
b4e8aa2c:  00000000  b3b8f93f  b4e8aae8  b4e8aa40
b4e8aa3c:  b39e5190  b39e5370  00000078  000001f5
b4e8aa4c:  00000000  00000177  00000000  5aa27f70
b4e8aa5c:  00000000  00000000  00000000  62cc4f93
b4e8aa6c:  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000012
b4e8aa7c: >00000000  0000130a  00000000  000041ed
b4e8aa8c:  00000001  00000000  00000000  00000000
b4e8aa9c:  00000000  00001000  00000000  00001000
b4e8aaac:  00000000  00000008  00000000  5f923943
b4e8aabc:  00000000  3b023380  00000000  5f92394b
b4e8aacc:  00000000  0c845880  00000000  5f923960
b4e8aadc:  00000000  160dc080  00000000  00000000
b4e8aaec:  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000
runtime.dumpregs(0x130a)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_arm.go:23 +0x39a

goroutine 38 [syscall]:
runtime.cgocall(0xf0c764, 0x1205e994, 0x150001)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:128 +0x64 fp=0x1205e970 sp=0x1205e958 pc=0x121e4
os/user._Cfunc_mygetpwuid_r(0x0, 0x12208380, 0xb4400510, 0x400, 0x121dc208, 0x0)
        _cgo_gotypes.go:171 +0x38 fp=0x1205e990 sp=0x1205e970 pc=0x152a64
os/user.lookupUnixUid.func1.1(0x0, 0x12208380, 0xb4400510, 0x400, 0x121dc208, 0x4)
        /usr/local/go/src/os/user/cgo_lookup_unix.go:100 +0x104 fp=0x1205e9b4 sp=0x1205e990 pc=0x154198
os/user.lookupUnixUid.func1(0x8)
        /usr/local/go/src/os/user/cgo_lookup_unix.go:100 +0x40 fp=0x1205e9d0 sp=0x1205e9b4 pc=0x154244
os/user.retryWithBuffer(0x121dc210, 0x1205ea48, 0x121dc210, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/os/user/cgo_lookup_unix.go:253 +0x2c fp=0x1205e9fc sp=0x1205e9d0 pc=0x153850
os/user.lookupUnixUid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/os/user/cgo_lookup_unix.go:96 +0xc4 fp=0x1205ea5c sp=0x1205e9fc pc=0x152e8c
os/user.current(0x1205ea94, 0x8, 0x7eb40)
        /usr/local/go/src/os/user/cgo_lookup_unix.go:49 +0x18 fp=0x1205ea70 sp=0x1205ea5c pc=0x152d24
os/user.Current.func1()
        /usr/local/go/src/os/user/lookup.go:11 +0x14 fp=0x1205ea88 sp=0x1205ea70 pc=0x153fec
sync.(*Once).Do(0x1cfe2b0, 0x132a848)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/once.go:44 +0xb8 fp=0x1205eaa0 sp=0x1205ea88 pc=0x7eb54
os/user.Current(0x0, 0x1cfe120, 0x1a4350)
        /usr/local/go/src/os/user/lookup.go:11 +0x24 fp=0x1205eab4 sp=0x1205eaa0 pc=0x152450
os/user.LookupId(0x1316e8a, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/os/user/lookup.go:38 +0x14 fp=0x1205ead8 sp=0x1205eab4 pc=0x152520
archive/tar.statUnix(0x144fd20, 0x120386c0, 0x122fa280, 0xd736db66, 0xe)
        /usr/local/go/src/archive/tar/stat_unix.go:39 +0x6c0 fp=0x1205ec14 sp=0x1205ead8 pc=0x1a4364
archive/tar.FileInfoHeader(0x144fd20, 0x120386c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xae16c, 0x120386c0, 0x12202590)
        /usr/local/go/src/archive/tar/common.go:699 +0x388 fp=0x1205ecf0 sp=0x1205ec14 pc=0x19d684
github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive.FileInfoHeader(0x12202595, 0x8, 0x144fd20, 0x120386c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x85d8c0, 0x1156ff0, 0x120c13e0)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:361 +0x34 fp=0x1205ed48 sp=0x1205ecf0 pc=0x85232c
github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive.(*tarAppender).addTarFile(0x12208320, 0x12202590, 0xd, 0x12202595, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:472 +0x9c fp=0x1205eda0 sp=0x1205ed48 pc=0x852b18
github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive.TarWithOptions.func1.2(0x12202590, 0xd, 0x144fd20, 0x12038630, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1cfe640, 0xae16c)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:885 +0x478 fp=0x1205eea4 sp=0x1205eda0 pc=0x85d948
path/filepath.walk(0x12202590, 0xd, 0x144fd20, 0x12038630, 0x122c6330, 0x0, 0x30)
        /usr/local/go/src/path/filepath/path.go:357 +0x2dc fp=0x1205ef08 sp=0x1205eea4 pc=0xef208
path/filepath.Walk(0x12202590, 0xd, 0x122c6330, 0x12869e6, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/path/filepath/path.go:403 +0xe0 fp=0x1205ef34 sp=0x1205ef08 pc=0xef318
github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive.TarWithOptions.func1(0x1222c050, 0x1441a18, 0x122bc090, 0x1200e290, 0x1200e278, 0x122bc070)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:803 +0x244 fp=0x1205efd4 sp=0x1205ef34 pc=0x85de70
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:1015 +0x4 fp=0x1205efd4 sp=0x1205efd4 pc=0x6b480
created by github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive.TarWithOptions
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive/archive.go:745 +0x1e8

goroutine 1 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).roundTrip(0x122fa1e0, 0x1220a4e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:2033 +0x464
net/http.(*Transport).RoundTrip(0x122fa140, 0x1248c000, 0x122fa140, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:422 +0x628
net/http.send(0x1248c000, 0x143cb10, 0x122fa140, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1200e558, 0x10, ...)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:252 +0x130
net/http.(*Client).send(0x125a7340, 0x1248c000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2, 0x1, 0x122fc580, ...)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:176 +0xb8
net/http.(*Client).Do(0x125a7340, 0x1248c000, 0x1203a088, 0x1248c000, 0x976b7963)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:615 +0x1d0
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context/ctxhttp.Do(0x144b2a0, 0x1203a088, 0x125a7340, 0x122c8180, 0x1220a3e0, 0x1294cf6, 0xc)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context/ctxhttp/ctxhttp.go:30 +0x50
github.com/docker/docker/client.(*Client).doRequest(0x12254980, 0x144b2a0, 0x1203a088, 0x122c8180, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/client/request.go:132 +0x5c
github.com/docker/docker/client.(*Client).sendRequest(0x12254980, 0x144b2a0, 0x1203a088, 0x128700c, 0x3, 0x12040400, 0x20, 0x1222bb10, 0xb4e9a500, 0x1200e298, ...)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/client/request.go:122 +0xc4
github.com/docker/docker/client.(*Client).putRaw(0x12254980, 0x144b2a0, 0x1203a088, 0x12040400, 0x20, 0x1222bb10, 0xb4e9a500, 0x1200e298, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/client/request.go:64 +0x80
github.com/docker/docker/client.(*Client).CopyToContainer(0x12254980, 0x144b2a0, 0x1203a088, 0xbee45dcd, 0xc, 0xbee45dda, 0x8, 0xb4e9a500, 0x1200e298, 0x0, ...)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/client/container_copy.go:47 +0x1a0
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/container.copyToContainer(0x144b2a0, 0x1203a088, 0x1459430, 0x122df130, 0x0, 0xbee45dc4, 0x8, 0xbee45dda, 0x8, 0xbee45dcd, ...)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/container/cp.go:272 +0x1d8
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/container.runCopy(0x1459430, 0x122df130, 0xbee45dc4, 0x8, 0xbee45dcd, 0x15, 0x0, 0x72deac, 0x1222bdf0)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/container/cp.go:104 +0x178
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/container.NewCopyCommand.func1(0x125a5e00, 0x122e8c90, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/container/cp.go:67 +0xb0
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x125a5e00, 0x120360b0, 0x2, 0x2, 0x125a5e00, 0x120360b0)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:762 +0x360
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x121168c0, 0x122c4cb8, 0x108db38, 0x122c4cc0)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:852 +0x20c
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0x121168c0, 0x121168c0, 0x143cd68)
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:800 +0x1c
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/cli/cmd/docker.Main()
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/cli/cmd/docker/docker.go:180 +0xa0
main.main()
        /balena-engine/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/cmd/balena-engine/main.go:27 +0xc0

goroutine 5 [syscall]:
os/signal.signal_recv(0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:139 +0x130
os/signal.loop()
        /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x14
created by os/signal.init.0
        /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x30

goroutine 25 [IO wait]:
internal/poll.runtime_pollWait(0xb4e90fc0, 0x72, 0x1220c000)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:173 +0x44
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait(0x125aff04, 0x72, 0xffffff00, 0x143f288, 0x1caac2c)
        /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:85 +0x8c
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead(0x125aff04, 0x1220c000, 0x1000, 0x1000)
        /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:90 +0x2c
internal/poll.(*FD).Read(0x125afef0, 0x1220c000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:157 +0x148
net.(*netFD).Read(0x125afef0, 0x1220c000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x1205ff04, 0x4)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:202 +0x38
net.(*conn).Read(0x121dc088, 0x1220c000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:176 +0x58
net/http.(*persistConn).Read(0x122fa1e0, 0x1220c000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x1205ff04, 0x2, 0x2)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1453 +0x174
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0x122c61e0)
        /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:100 +0x104
bufio.(*Reader).Peek(0x122c61e0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x12086680, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:132 +0x28
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0x122fa1e0)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1601 +0x14c
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1237 +0x7b0

goroutine 26 [select]:
io.(*pipe).Read(0x1209e120, 0x12548000, 0x8000, 0x8000, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1d1269c)
        /usr/local/go/src/io/pipe.go:50 +0xe0
io.(*PipeReader).Read(0x1200e288, 0x12548000, 0x8000, 0x8000, 0x0, 0x368034, 0x12052500)
        /usr/local/go/src/io/pipe.go:127 +0x38
net/http.transferBodyReader.Read(0x1222c0a0, 0x12548000, 0x8000, 0x8000, 0x8000, 0x8000, 0x1d1269c)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transfer.go:60 +0x40
io.copyBuffer(0xb4e9a530, 0x1200ed48, 0x143f138, 0x1222c0a0, 0x12548000, 0x8000, 0x8000, 0x10e0b10, 0x111a2c8, 0x1f400, ...)
        /usr/local/go/src/io/io.go:400 +0x14c
io.Copy(0xb4e9a530, 0x1200ed48, 0x143f138, 0x1222c0a0, 0x1200ed48, 0x1209e150, 0x3b9694, 0x8)
        /usr/local/go/src/io/io.go:362 +0x48
net/http.(*transferWriter).WriteBody(0x1222c0a0, 0x143a530, 0x122059c0, 0x2, 0x2)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transfer.go:330 +0xf0
net/http.(*Request).write(0x1248c000, 0x143a530, 0x122059c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/request.go:622 +0x4a8
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0x122fa1e0)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1825 +0x168
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1238 +0x7cc

trap    0x6
error   0x0
oldmask 0x0
r0      0xb988a054
r1      0xb988a000
r2      0x45731140
r3      0x85
r4      0x2
r5      0xa
r6      0xb4573114
r7      0xb4e8abc0
r8      0x1
r9      0xb4e8b7c0
r10     0x120015e0
fp      0x0
ip      0x23
sp      0xb4e8aa1c
lr      0xb3baf834
pc      0x52c6e
cpsr    0x800b0030
fault   0x46
```

I have used this command earlier for many times without this error.
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue with cp command?

Answer (score 2):

This is specific to the device you are using - the latest version of firmware on the AXC F 2152 from Phoenix Contact appears to have caused this change of behaviour. This can be resolved by getting in touch with Phoenix Contact and discussing the issue with them.

Comment: True. The latest firmware update of PLCNext caused this issue. Now Phonix is working to update the balena-engine app so it can be worked with the latest firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the container_id the container_name could work.

The version of Balena probably needs to be updated, it is an older version that is used here.

Alternative I have found in the system Podman
and Docker installation help is available on github. Maybe balena is out of focus.

https://github.com/PLCnext/Docker_GettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

Since the firmware 2023.0 LTS for the Phoenix Contact PLCnext Control devices support the container engine [podman](https://podman.io/) I would recommend switching to it. You can directly use podman as root user the same way you would use balena or docker.

For podman I can verify that copying files is possible with both the container name and the container id.